# Quadratic Equations with Unique Solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that a quadratic equation with real coefficients $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$, where $a\neq 0$ has a unique solution if and only if $\Delta=b^2-4ac=0$. This can be easily deduced from the quadratic formula

\begin{equation}
x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}.
\end{equation}
I attempted to prove this without making use of the quadratic formula. So here is my attempt: suppose that $x_0$ and $x_0^{\prime}$ are solutions to the quadratic equation $f(x)$. Then $ax_0^2+bx_0+c=a{x_0^{\prime}}^2+bx_0^{\prime}+c=0$, and
\begin{equation}
a(x_0^2-{x_0^{\prime}}^2)+b(x_0-x_0^{\prime})=0
\end{equation}
if and only if
\begin{equation}
(x_0-x_0^{\prime})[a(x_0+x_0^{\prime})+b]=0.
\end{equation}
I want to show that $a(x_0+x_0^{\prime})+b=0$ is impossible and from this, conclude that $x_0-x_0^{\prime}=0$ or $x_0=x_0^{\prime}$. How can I proceed?

Comment: You'll have to assume $c=b^2/(4a)$ somewhere, or you can't prove a result you're told requires it. Hint: show $ax^2+bx+b^2/(4a)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: You should try deriving the quadratic formula and setting the two solutions equal to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the quadratic equation
$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$
Since the equation is quadratic, $a \neq 0$, so we may divide both sides of the equation by $a$ to obtain
$$x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{c}{a} = 0$$
Since $a \neq 0$, $r_1$ and $r_2$ are also roots of this monic quadratic equation.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{c}{a} & = (x - r_1)(x - r_2)\\
                                 & = x^2 - r_2x - r_1x + r_1r_2\\
                                 & = x^2 - (r_1 + r_2)x + r_1r_2
\end{align*}
Since the equation
$$x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{c}{a} = x^2 - (r_1 + r_2)x + r_1r_2$$
is an identity, we can match coefficients to obtain the system of equations
\begin{align*}
r_1 + r_2 & = -\frac{b}{a}\\
r_1r_2 & = \frac{c}{a}
\end{align*}

Suppose that $$b^2 - 4ac = 0$$ Since $b = -a(r_1 + r_2)$ and $c = ar_1r_2$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
[-a(r_1 + r_2)]^2 - 4a(ar_1r_2) & = 0\\
a^2(r_1 + r_2)^2 - 4a^2r_1r_2 & = 0\\
a^2(r_1^2 + 2r_1r_2 + r_2^2) - 4a^2r_1r_2 & = 0\\
a^2[r_1^2 + 2r_1r_2 + r_2^2) - 4r_1r_2] & = 0\\
a^2(r_1^2 - 2r_1r_2 + r_2^2) & = 0\\
a^2(r_1 - r_2)^2 & = 0
\end{align*}
Since $a \neq 0$, $a^2 \neq 0$.  Hence,
$$(r_1 - r_2)^2 = 0$$
Since the only number with square zero is zero,
\begin{align*}
r_1 - r_2 & = 0\\
r_1 & = r_2
\end{align*}

Now suppose that $r_1 = r_2$.  Then
\begin{align*}
r_1 - r_2 & = 0\\
(r_1 - r_2)^2 & = 0\\
r_1^2 - 2r_1r_2 + r_1r_2 & = 0\\
r_1^2 + 2r_1r_2 + r_1r_2 - 4r_1r_2 & = 0\\
(r_1 + r_2)^2 - 4r_1r_2 & = 0\\
\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^2 - 4\left(\frac{c}{a}\right) & = 0\\
\frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{4c}{a} & = 0\\
\frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2} & = 0\\
b^2 - 4ac & = 0 
\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent, I like your solution!!! Quite elegant solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The equation you got, namely

\begin{equation}
(x_0-x_0^{\prime})[a(x_0+x_0^{\prime})+b]=0\quad (1).
\end{equation}

only used

$$ax_0^2+bx_0+c=a{x_0^{\prime}}^2+bx_0^{\prime}+c$$

but did not use the essential fact that $x_0,x_0'$ are roots!  Essentially, you showed that if a parabola has the same value at two points, either the two points coincide (i.e. $x_0-x_0^{\prime}=0$) or they sum to $-b/a$ (i.e. $a(x_0+x_0^{\prime})+b=0$).  In fact, by symmetry, they always must sum to $-b/a$ since the vertex is at $-b/(2a).$

At the end of the day, the quadratic formula is just completing the square.  If you don't want to explicitly use the formula, I suspect your proof would implicitly end up doing so via completing the square.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a\neq 0$ (otherwise the equation is linear). Note that

**Algebraic method**:

$$aX^2+bX+c=a\left(X+\frac b{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}+c$$

This is $0$ if and only if
$$4a^2\left(X+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2=b^2-4ac$$

And this equation has exactly one solution only if $b^2-4ac=0$.

**Analytic method** (well, it has some hidden algebra):

A parabola and a line can share two, one or zero points. The function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ describes a parabola (not easy to show, see Dandelin spheres proof). Its axis is "vertical", that is, parallel to $Y$ axis.

The only way that the parabola meets the $X$ axis at only one point is that this point is the vertex of the parabola, that is, its maximum or its minimum.

Since $f'(x)=2ax+b$, the vertex is $\left(\dfrac{-b}{2a},\dfrac{b^2}{4a}-\dfrac{b^2}{2a}+c\right)$, so the vertex is at axis $Y$ only if $b^2-4ac=0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your line of reasoning from which the rest follow.

$ax^2+bx+c=0$ is not ***an*** equation but a family of equations with $3$ cases (one,two or no solutions).

When you make an assumption that the equation has only one root and wish to derive a condition under which this holds, you are restricting the original to members of that family where these conditions hold. So far so good.

But then you claim that the original assumption doesn't hold, thus reverting to  examining the other two cases.

And indeed, if two solutions do exist, $a(x_0+x'_0)+b=0$, does hold.

Perhaps if we apply the same (fallacious) logic to a simpler form of the equation it will become clear.

Let's examine: $ax^2+b=0, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

We wish to see what happens when this has only one solution.

We assume it has two solutions, $x, x_0$.

Then $ax^2+b=0, ax_0^2+b=0 \Rightarrow a(x-x_0)(x+x_0)=0$

Now we have to show that $a=0$ **and** $x+x_0$ are impossible and from this, conclude that $x=x_0$.